# How do I specify the shell executable for child_process.exec?

Tags: node.js, windows, git-bash

I'm using GitBash in windows 10 and want to execute git commands within a child_process.exec call. I think that since I installed git through "Git For Windows", I just need specify the shell as the GitBash executable. I've tried every variation of the path to GitBash executable that I could think of and it always fails. What is the path that node is looking for?

Example of paths that do not work

`c:/program files/git/usr/bin/bash
c:/program\ files/git/usr/bin/bash
/c/program\ files/git/usr/bin/bash
c:\\program files\\git\\usr\\bin\\bash`

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

describe.only('exec', function(){
    it('should work', function(done){
        let shellPath = "c:\\program files\\git\\usr\\bin\\bash";
        expect(exec(`cat <<< "abc"`, { shell: shellPath }, (err, stdout) => {
            expect(err).to.be.null;
            expect(stdout.trim()).to.be.equal("abc");
            done();
        }));
    });
});
```

The first assertion fails with:

```
expected [Error: Command failed: cat <<< "abc" << was unexpected at this time.] to be null
```

Comment: You didn't specify what fails. Full error message could help this question to appear in search results, at least.

Comment: The test fails whenever I use a command that the Windows command shell doesn't understand. If I use , `pwd` for instance, I can get an expected response.

Comment: Ultimately I want to run git commands through a shell which I thought required me to use bash since git is installed through [GitForWindows](https://gitforwindows.org/). I see now though that I can `exec` git commands through the default shell.

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of installing Windows-specific git. It can be used as any other command from cmd.exe or any other Windows shell. You don't need custom shell indeed to run `git` specifically.

Comment: @estus I edited my question to make it clearer as to my intent. If you reword your answer to include your last comment, I think that would make a better answer.

Comment: Sure, updated it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some problems with this approach.

As [the reference](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_shell_requirements) states, `exec` [automatically uses Windows-specific shell arguments](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v10.11.0/lib/child_process.js#L477) that won't work for Bash.

Another problem is that `PATH` may not be set to GitBash binaries path.

This should likely work:

```
delete process.platform;
process.platform = 'linux';

exec(`cat <<< "abc"`, {
  env: { PATH: 'C:\\Program Files\\git\\usr\\bin' },
  shell: 'C:\\Program Files\\git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe'
}, (err, stdout) => {
  ...
});

process.platform = 'win32';
```

The workability of this solution may depend on `bash.exe` implementation.

The use of custom shell isn't needed to run `git` in Node; this is handled by Git executable.

Comment: it didn't work. Node is still calling the windows cmd.exe. I took a look at [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs/blob/master/src/exec.js) but couldn't see how they were getting the bash shell to execute.

Comment: err.message has more information `/c/Program: Files\\git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe does not exist`. See how the path is getting mangled? If I change shell path to `/c/Program\ Files/git/usr/bin/bash.exe`, I get an EOENT error.

Comment: *nix can have problems with windows paths but this problem is likely specific to your bash build which seems to be crippled. I checked it with Mingw, Cygwin and Git Portable (contains custom Mingw build), all of them worked. As for shelljs, it seems to use same `shell` option, so I'd expect it to behave the same. Did you check it?

Comment: If a space causes the problem, try to use `C:\\progra~1\\...` path instead.

Comment: I get what shelljs is doing now and that is replicating bash behavior through nodejs, not by actually using the bash shell.

Comment: I supposed you referred to shelljs.exec, didn't you?

Comment: I'm using [Git For Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) which is a fork of Msys2 afaik

Comment: if encase the shell path into quotes within the back ticks, then I can get bash to launch. But now the err is an integer of 1.

Comment: Quotes didn't work for me in paths. Did you try progra~1 trick?